# FB Login button not prompting first time users for scope

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

```
"<div id='fb-root'></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() 
    {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'ID', 
            status: true, 
            cookie: true, 
            xfbml: true  
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) 
        {
              if(response.status === 'connected') 
                {
                    if (response.authResponse != 'undefined') 
                    {
                        window.location = '/fb_redirect.php';
                    }
                } else if(response.status === 'not_authorized')
                {

                } else 
                {
                    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) 
                    {
                        window.location = '/fb_redirect.php';
                    });
                }
            });
        };

        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=ID';
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>

<div class='fb-login-button' data-show-faces='false' scope='email' registration-url='http://www.sportannica.com/fb_redirect.php' size='large' data-width='200' data-max-rows='1'></div>
```

This is what I'm using right now. For users that have already accepted the app, it works fine. But, for first time users, upon click of the login button, there isn't any screen that pops up and shows details about the app like how many people use it or what type of permissions it is requesting. It just heads right to /fb_redirect.php.

[image]

See the Site URL that is specified in the pic? Is that the URL that the page is redirected to upon logging into FB and accepting the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The login button is used when the user is not logged in on facebook, if the user is logged in but hasn't granted permission to your app you should use the oauth dialog for example.

You can accomplish that by doing this

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if(response.status === 'connected'){
        if (response.authResponse != 'undefined')
            window.location = '/fb_redirect.php';
    }else if(response.status === 'not_authorized'){
    //it means we have a user but he hasn't granted any permissions to our app
    //we're going to redirect him to the permission page
    window.location = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=YOUR_APP_URL&scope=email';
    } else {
    //the user is not logged in, as you already have a login button you don't have to do nothing  
    }
});

//this should be outside the FB.getLoginStatus function
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
    window.location = '/fb_redirect.php';
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But, in the fb_redirect file... a session started or if it is a first time user an insert query will be executed. Does that all need to happen on the same page that the login button is on?

Comment: Can you explain yourself better?

Comment: The internet that I'm connected to right now won't let me connect to my remote server via ftp. So, I can't upload your code to see if it works or not. But, from previous experiences, window.location = 'some_other_file.php' never worked. For some reason, window.reload() has seemed to work just fine though.

Comment: Oh sorry, the redirect can be whatever you want as long as it's inside you're domain. The url you specified on the app details will be the the one who will receive the signed_request

Comment: Okay. So when a user accepts the app, I need to fetch some of their info that I'm requesting thru the app using $user = $facebook->getUser();

Comment: And $user_profile = $facebook->api("/me", "GET", array('access_token' => $access_token));. Does that need to happen on the same page that receives the signed request?

Comment: No, I've noticed that you're using javascript SDK and the option cookie is TRUE. Thanks to that you can use the facebook php sdk to fetch the data from the user you just need to do this $user_profile = $this->facebook->api('/me','GET'); You don't even need to pass the token

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I'll test this as soon as I get home.

Comment: Allrigh, give some feedback, if something goes wrong maybe I can help you out

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26758/discussion-between-lance-and-fabio-antunes)

Answer (score 0):

the correct syntax is `data-scope="email"`, not `scope="email"`.